# why selected cell in collection view doesn't show correctly in the UICollection View Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift3, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, selectedindex

I am using swift 3 and I have collection view in my app that shows iPhone gallery in that . every things are good But I want the user could select some photos and this can be happen But the problem is that I used another small image in every cells that when the user select that cell the picture will showing a tick that user could understand that cell has been selected - this will work at the beginning but when the user scroll the collection view some cells that user didn't select them has this tick too! 
**Remember that select and did deselect are working well and the problem is just for showing this tick **
**I have image with tag in cell and that image will showing a tick or nothing when the user select the cell or didDeselect that **

I know that these codes are more than you think But many some Guys need to access all of the codes so you can see my codes below

```
 import UIKit
 import Photos
 class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {
let arr_img = NSMutableArray()

@IBOutlet var collview: UICollectionView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let allPhotosOptions : PHFetchOptions = PHFetchOptions.init()
    allPhotosOptions.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "creationDate", ascending: true)]
    let allPhotosResult = PHAsset.fetchAssets(with: .image, options: allPhotosOptions)
    allPhotosResult.enumerateObjects({ (asset, idx, stop) in

        self.arr_img.add(asset)
    })

}
func getAssetThumbnail(asset: PHAsset, size: CGFloat) -> UIImage {
    let retinaScale = UIScreen.main.scale
    let retinaSquare = CGSize(width: size * retinaScale, height: size * retinaScale)//CGSizeMake(size * retinaScale, size * retinaScale)
    let cropSizeLength = min(asset.pixelWidth, asset.pixelHeight)
    let square = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: cropSizeLength, height: cropSizeLength)//CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(cropSizeLength), CGFloat(cropSizeLength))
    let cropRect = square.applying(CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0/CGFloat(asset.pixelWidth), y: 1.0/CGFloat(asset.pixelHeight)))

    let manager = PHImageManager.default()
    let options = PHImageRequestOptions()
    var thumbnail = UIImage()

    options.isSynchronous = true
    options.deliveryMode = .highQualityFormat
    options.resizeMode = .exact
    options.normalizedCropRect = cropRect

    manager.requestImage(for: asset, targetSize: retinaSquare, contentMode: .aspectFit, options: options, resultHandler: {(result, info)->Void in
        thumbnail = result!
    })
    return thumbnail
}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//MARK:
//MARK: Collectioview methods
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return arr_img.count
}
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                    cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell",
                                                  for: indexPath)
    let imgview : UIImageView = cell.viewWithTag(20) as! UIImageView
    imgview.image = self.getAssetThumbnail(asset: self.arr_img.object(at: indexPath.row) as! PHAsset, size: 150)

    return cell
}

}

 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
 let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)
    if cell!.isSelected == true {


        print(indexPath)
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        print("Cell is Selected!")
        let selectView : UIImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(22) as! UIImageView
        selectView.image = UIImage(named: "Select.png")
    }

    else if cell!.isSelected != true        {

        collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

    cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        let selectView : UIImageView = cell?.viewWithTag(22) as! UIImageView
        selectView.image = nil

        print("Cell is  Not Selected!")

    }

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

    print(indexPath)
    if cell?.isSelected == true {
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
        print("Cell is Selected In Deselect!")
        let selectView : UIImageView = cell!.viewWithTag(22) as! UIImageView
        selectView.image = nil
        collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

    }
    else if cell?.isSelected != true        {
        cell?.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        collectionView.cellForItem(at: indexPath as IndexPath)

        print("Cell is DeSelected!")
        let selectView : UIImageView = cell!.viewWithTag(22) as! UIImageView
        selectView.image = nil


    }

}
```

Comment: The cells are reused like a tableview cell. You need to maintain an array of checked cells and set the tick image after dequeueing the cell.

Comment: why did write didDeselectItemAt ? because your code works with didSelect only.

Comment: Cells are reused. Add a property `isSelected` to the model, update it in `didSelect/didDeselect` and set the tick depending on that property in `cellForItem`.

Comment: or you can add indxPath to array in didSelect method. and check that in cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: @RoboticCat and KKRocks: Declaring extra arrays is a bad suggestion. The information is supposed to be included in the data model.

Comment: these are good Advice But please help me with writing a codes here

Comment: @SaeedRahmatolahi Please check out my answer and if is worked then please accept my answer and upvote same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take a button inside your cell and give tag to it.

Take array and do following.

```
let arr_selected = NSMutableArray()
```

---

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell",
                                                      for: indexPath)

        let btn_check : UIButton = cell.viewWithTag(30) as! UIButton
        if arr_selected.contains(indexPath.row){
            btn_check.isSelected = true
        }else{
            btn_check.isSelected = false
        }
        return cell
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath){
        if arr_selected.contains(indexPath.row){
            arr_selected.remove(indexPath.row)
        }else{
            arr_selected.add(indexPath.row)
        }
        self.collview.reloadData()
    }
```

if you want demo, then you can download from [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qtos2idgfgbbs9p/PHOTO_LAYOUT_iOS_BENZATINE.zip?dl=0)

Comment: how can I use the image for selected or deselected button?

Comment: ok you want to use image then take imageview instead button so when this condition arr_selected.contains(indexPath.row) == true change your imageview as selected else unselect @SaeedRahmatolahi

Comment: It's My pleasure. @SaeedRahmatolahi

Comment: its worked Just one more question how can I storage the selected images to an array?

Comment: you already stored selected images into array in  arr_selected. Just print("\( arr_selected)") you will get all selected images indexpath.

Comment: Thanks A lot Please Vote this question and thanks a lot for helping

Comment: I couldn't get the selected images and I couldn't add them to UIImage Array Please help me